# Add linked server from SQL-Server to MySQL: "Data source name not found" (Error:7303)

Tags: sql-server, mysql, sql-server-2005, mysql-5.5, windows-server

I'm trying to link my SQL-Server 2005 on Windows Server 2008 R2 with MySQL 5.5.40 on a different computer. I have followed this guide:

http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/

However, when i try to test the connection under "Linked Servers" as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

i'm getting this error:

[image]

The ODBC data source was added as shown in above link as you can see here:

[image]

What can be the reason for this? Note that the Server2008 is a 64bit OS, if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ODBC Connection needs to be a System DSN. The connection is made as the service account, not you, and so the service account doesn't know about your User DSN.

From [the article](http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/):

> Select the System DSN tab to configure a data source for the entire
>   system.

Comment: Thanks, i've realized it already. But i've still problems to connect. Maybe you know why. I get "access denied" and  "using password no" which indicates that the password defined in the ODBC data source is not even used in MySql. Do you have an idea why? Because if i click "Test" in the MySql-Connector for the ODBC datasource(image above) it connects and authenticates successfully.

Comment: Now it seems to work (at least the connection part). I've get it to work  with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2977289/284240).